# Printing hex string

Tags: python, hex, string-formatting

```
print 'Payload: ', struct.unpack('%dB'%len(payload), payload)
print '%08x (%d bits) DATA: ' % (identifier, width), repr(payload)
```

These two code statements generate the following results:

```
Payload: (125, 255, 255, 125, 255, 255, 125, 255)
18feef00 (29 bits) DATA: '}\xff\xff}\xff\xff}\xff'
```

I'd like to have ONE final string that has the correct hex data that looks like this:

```
7dffff7dffff7dff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> tup = (125, 255, 255, 125, 255, 255, 125, 255)
>>> "".join('%02x' % i for i in tup)
'7dffff7dffff7dff'
```

So, in your case, you can use `struct.unpack` to construct the tuple and then use the `"".join()` to construct the string.

It's unclear what you are starting with, but if it's the string `'}\xff\xff}\xff\xff}\xff'` then this works without the tuple:

```
>>> s = '}\xff\xff}\xff\xff}\xff'
>>> "".join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in s)
'7dffff7dffff7dff'
```